# How to iterate through a python list of dictionaries 

Tags: python, django, dictionary

This is my dictionary:

```
[{'entity': 'first entity', 'place': ['first', 'second', 'abc']}, {'entity': 'second entity', 'place': ['awe', 'ert']}]
```

and I want to print the values this way:

```
-first entity
-first, second, abc

-second entity
-awe, ert
```

I tried a lot of things but I don't know how to deal with the list of the second key

Could you also suggest me how to do the same in a Django template?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for python code,

```
a = [{'entity': 'first entity', 'place': ['first', 'second', 'abc']}, {'entity': 'second entity', 'place': ['awe', 'ert']}]
for x in a:
    print '-', x['entity']
    print '-', ','.join(x['place'])
```

for django template:

```
<p>
{% for x in a %}
    {{x.entity}} <br/>
    {% for y in x.place %}
        {{y}}
    {% endfor %} 
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for d in my_list:
    print "-%s\n-%s" % (d['entity'], ", ".join(d['place']))
```

First, note that what you called "my dictionary" is actually a list of dictionaries, I called in `my_list` here.  Each of those dictionaries has an `'entity'` key, which is easy to print.  The `'place'` key has a list for a value.  I use `.join()` to combine all the strings in that list with a comma-space string to produce the human-readable list that you want.

Comment: many thanks Ned! I know you answered first, but @pinkdawn also shows the code for django template! Thanks again.